# PHP/XML - Fixing writing script

Tags: php, html, xml, file-io

im Lighty, a new programmer and student, i'm following a small tutorial at the moment, reading an XML file and displaying it with PHP, one thing i want to do myself, is writing data to my XML file, from a PHP script, using a Form in HTML, my script and form look like this:

```
<?php

    echo ('Script started');

    ///making sure the script only works when posted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        echo ('-Post accepted');

        //Load XML File into variable
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("phptest3.xml");
        echo ('-XML Loaded');

        //Connect form to Variables 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  echo ('-Vars connected');

  //Function to strip items that are not needed to prevend XSS/Injections
        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
  echo ('-Injections stripped');

        //Create new children in XML file and Connect the from data to the corresponding XML entries
        $xml->people[0];
        $xml->people->addChild('person');
        $xml->person[0];
        $xml->person->addChild('name', $name);
        $xml->person->addChild('age', $age);
        $xml->person->addChild('sex', $sex);
        $xml->person->addChild('comment', $comment);
        echo ('-Data inserted');

        //Save current data to XML file...
        $xml->savexml('phptest3.xml');
        echo ('-saved');
    }

    echo ('-Script ended.');

?>
```

While my XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
<person>
    <name>Lighty</name>
    <age>17</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <comment>iets</comment>
    <name>iets</name><age>75</age><sex>F</sex><comment>igjk</comment>       <name>iets</name><age>75</age><sex>M</sex><comment>gergsrh</comment></person>
</people>
```

now, it does insert data now, but it puts it where it shouldnt put it :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No such simplexml method as save(). You can use saveXML instead.

```
$_POST['name'] = 'testName';
$_POST['age'] = '15';
$_POST['sex'] = 'F';
$_POST['comment'] = 'test comment';
//Load XML File into variable
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

//Connect form to Variables 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

//Create new children in XML file and Connect the from data to the corresponding XML entries    
$xml->program = "";
$xml->program->addChild('name', $name);
$xml->program->addChild('age', $age);
$xml->program->addChild('sex', $sex);
$xml->program->addChild('comment', $comment);

//Save current data to XML file...
$xml->saveXML('test.xml');
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>

<person>
    <name>Lighty</name>
    <age>17</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <comment>eyayayayaya</comment>
</person>

<program><name>testName</name><age>15</age><sex>F</sex><comment>test comment</comment></program></people>
```

Edit:

You said you got an error, why didn't you post it? Because when I tried to execute your script, I got quite a clear error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::save()`.

Comment: im sorry, still new to this, and indeed, it stops giving errors after making it saveXML,
only problem is now, that it shows up as an edit, but only as " temporary", like it doesnt have permission towrite, struggling now to get the file perms for writing right

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'edit, but only as "temporary"'? Can you give some data/examples?

Comment: well, i fixed that part by now, the problem now is that it adds the data IN the people child, the XML looks folllowing:
    <people>
    <person>
    <name> blablabla
    </person>
    </people>
it SHOULD add a new person tag after the closing tag of person, in people, but it doesnt, it shits it just after the last tag under the first person tag, and adds an extra closing tag for people and person, not even creating opening tags

Comment: it would be way easier if you just posted new xml data.

Comment: edited the question with the new script and xml